# Convert number from base-10 number system to any number system

Tags: c#, object-oriented, comparative-review, number-systems

I wrote a small method for convert number from base-10 number system to any number system (code is not perfect but that is not the point).
My question is if I get right single responsibility principle. Is 2nd approach better than 1st or 'charReplace' functionality is too small for creating own method ?

```
    public static string convertNumber(BigInteger num, int baseNum)
    {
        string symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        if (baseNum < 2 || symbols.Length + 10 < baseNum)
        {
            throw new Exception;
        }

        var result = "";
        do
        {
            var partResult = (int)(num % baseNum);
            if (partResult >= 10)
            {
                result = result.Insert(0, symbols[partResult - 10].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                result = result.Insert(0, partResult.ToString());
            }
            num /= baseNum;
        } while (num != 0);

        return result;
    }
```

vs.

```
    static readonly string Symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static string convertNumber(BigInteger num, int baseNum)
    {
        if (baseNum < 2 || Symbols.Length + 10 < baseNum)
        {
            throw new Exception;
        }

        var result = "";
        do
        {
            var partResult = (int)(num % baseNum);
            result = result.Insert(0, charReplace(partResult));
            num /= baseNum;
        } while (num != 0);

        return result;
    }

    private static string charReplace(int number){
        if (number < 10){
            return number.ToString();
        }

        return Symbols[number - 10].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Pedantic note: `BigInteger` is not exactly a "base-10" number. It is just abstractly a number. While it's true that `BigInteger.Parse()` and `BigInteger.ToString()` both work in base ten, the `BigInteger` itself isn't in any particular base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the 1st approach is good enough since it *personally* more readable.

Little suggestions

- I'd prefer to store the whole alphabet in the `symbols` string, instead of only letters. This could simplify the logic.
- You can calculate the resulting length of the output string and avoid string insertions.

Summarizing:

```
public static string ConvertNumber(BigInteger num, int baseNum)
{
    const string symbols = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if (baseNum < 2 || symbols.Length < baseNum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(baseNum));
    }

    if (num < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(num));
    }

    var resultLength = 1 + Math.Max((int)BigInteger.Log(num, baseNum), 0);
    var result = new char[resultLength];
    int index = resultLength - 1;
    do
    {
        result[index--] = symbols[(int)(num % baseNum)];
        num /= baseNum;
    } while (num != 0);

    return new string(result);
}
```

PS. It's recommended to name all classes and all methods in UpperCamelCase regardless of their publicity.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why is there Math.Max() ?

Comment: @GRO Because `if (num == 0)` the log is `-Infinity`.